# Wpf DataContext и потоки

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, background, task

Вопрос скорее идеологический, как правильно подходить к задаче обновления данных в ModelView.

Имеем DataContext, к нему привязан класс ModelView где так же в нем есть функции обработки данных ObservableCollection. Операции связаны с большим объемом данных, по этому во время обработки ui интерфейс замораживается. Очевидно что можно использовать Task,Thread,BackgroundWorker, но .. Как только наступает работа с коллекциями, так возникает необходимость вернуться в поток с ui через Dispatcher, иначе возникает ошибка доступа из другого потока.
Но, 99% времени занимает работа именно с коллекциями, и возвращаться в ui поток приходится постоянно, что сводит на `нет` все усилия выделить эту процедуру в отдельный поток.

Как идеологический более правильно решать такую задачу? Отключать DataContext на время обновления ?

P.S. в дополнение к дискуссии опубликую прототип `ObservableCollection` с "пониженным" числом уведомлений `NotifyChange`:) может пригодиться кому, хотя вещь простая.

```
public class ObservableCollectionExtension<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool __isNotify = true;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (__isNotify)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void NotifyOff()
    {
        __isNotify = false;
    }

    public void NotifyOn()
    {
        __isNotify = true;
        base.OnCollectionChanged(new 
             NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                   NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ClearNoNotify()
    {
        NotifyOff();
        ClearItems();
        NotifyOn();
    }
}
```

Comment: `99% времени занимает работа именно с коллекциями` что именно с ними делаете?

Comment: Ну что обычно делают с коллекциями, обновляют полученными данными и сортируют. Фактически данные удаляются и заливаются новые.

Comment: Что значит обновляют данными? Изменяете данные, что уже в коллекции? Зачем коллекцию сортировать несколько раз? Можно один раз отсортировать и потом вставлять в нужные места элементы. В чем смысл на каждый чих обновлять УИ? Если у вас события однотипные, можете их группировать и обновлять УИ пореже.

Comment: Суть вопроса в ином, как быть с потоками и привязкой к DataContext, а не про данные в коллекции. Дело в ошибке доступа из другого потока, если заганять обработку в параллельные задачи.

Comment: никак, если используете ObservableCollection - они требуют обновления только из УИ потока. Потому, если это проблема, то надо либо использовать что то другое, либо уменьшать количество телодвижений с коллекцией, чтобы УИ не фризило

Comment: А что то другое это что? С учётом биндинга к этому всему..

Comment: Ну, в моем приложении я такое решил троттлингом - то есть группировкой событий, что позволило пореже обновлять УИ. А вообще где то видел в интернете, что народ строгает свои коллекции, чтобы иметь возможность пачку операций над ней сделать, а событие на обновления УИ вызвать только раз при этом.

Comment: Да, про свое тоже понятно, именно так и сделано, одно обновление генерить, а не 5к+ :)

Comment: Вариант решения на ReactiveUI: https://habr.com/post/303898/

Comment: Реакт это безусловно интересно, но проблемы доступа из других потоков кажется не решает, хотя может я невнимательно читал.

Comment: Правильный ответ - отключать коллекцию от UI на время работы. UI на то и существует, чтобы взаимодействовать с данными и не его вина, что вы часто работаете с коллекцией, он обязан обновлять все изменения коллекции, иначе это не интерфейс, а фигня какая-то. В вашем случае я виде два пути: 1) если нужны громоздкие работы, то создавайте копию коллекции, работайте с ней и в конце заменяйте исходную коллекцию. Памяти не больше сожрёт, если у вас коллекция классов. 2) отключать исходную коллекцию, а в интерфейсе ставите заглушку, где будет написано, что данные обновляются и типа подождите.

Comment: Да, пока сделано по первому из предложенных вами путей, второй вариант тоже имеет право на жизнь.